# How to Force Dark Mode if "Force Dark Mode" from developer options doesn't work?

Tags: applications, android-11, dark-mode

Even after activating the dark mode option from developer options in the setting,

[image]

some apps still have a white screen.

> [image]

Although few apps have been successfully forced in the dark mode.

[image]

Is there a way to force the app to have black background somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that aside from @MorrisonChang 's answer, you can still give these a try:

- Many devices have a native accessibility setting called "high contrast" mode; this will usually achieve a similar effect to Dark Mode.  Note that there is generally a similar feature called "invert colors" which, while not as aesthetically pleasing, can at the very least help with the glare when you have an app that doesn't work with Dark Mode.
- Note that Chrome itself (or ***potentially*** your native browser, YMMV based on make and model) has at least two flags that can be toggled for Dark Mode (actually, these may also vary based on device and architecture), they *might* help with apps that call the webview class through intent:
  `chrome://flags#enable-force-dark`
  `chrome://flags#inherit-native-theme-from-parent-widget`

Comment: The High contrast does work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR: Ask the developer of the app to support Dark Mode.**

Android 10 added support for [Dark Mode/Dark Theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) in apps. Prior to Android 10, light/dark mode was supported via theme/style library. As you've discovered there is a 'Force Dark Mode' setting in Developer Options. From the documentation:

> Force Dark analyzes each view of your light-themed app, and applies a dark theme automatically before it is drawn to the screen. Some developers use a mix of Force Dark and native implementation to cut down on the amount of time needed to implement Dark theme.
>
> Apps must opt-in to Force Dark by setting `android:forceDarkAllowed="true"` in the activity's theme.

So it is on the developer of an app to support Dark Mode.

Also realize that the developer may be using a third-party framework similar to a game engine which doesn't check any theme state.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to try the [DarQ](https://github.com/KieronQuinn/DarQ) application for Android 10 and higher.

> DarQ provides a per-app selectable force dark option for Android 10
> and above.
>
> It uses a root or [Shizuku](https://shizuku.rikka.app/) (ADB) service to apply the theme
> seamlessly and quickly, without needing an accessibility service. DarQ
> also provides an option to apply the system dark theme (as well as
> selectable force dark).

Refer to detailed [instructions](https://shizuku.rikka.app/guide/setup/) for setting up shizuku

This works perfectly for apps that have an option to force dark mode see sample screenshots below:

[image]  [image] [image]

<sup>Credits: Quinny899 XDA images</sup>